# How to downgrade Kotlin in Intellij 15

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, uninstallation, kotlin

For a project of mine I need to use Kotlin 1.0.0-1038 (beta), but to install it I probably need to uninstall the newer version of kotlin, but it has no uninstall button where it should have.

[image]

How would I downgrade Kotlin? IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4

Comment: Did you try downloading an old version of the plugin manually and using "install plugin from disk"?

Comment: Yes, but nothing seems to change, because I cannot get rid of the newer version.

Comment: There is no good way to downgrade the bundled Kotlin plugin. The best thing you can do is upgrade your project to Kotlin 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IMPORTANT UPD:** as @yole commented, this is a bad solution as it will break things.  There is no proper way to downgrade a bundled plugin without breaking the installation. Instead, consider upgrading the project to the up-to-date Kotlin version.

You have the plugin bundled with IntelliJ IDEA. **On your own risk**, you can delete its folder manually from IntelliJ IDEA installation (`plugins/kotlin` subfolder). After that you will be able to install whatever compatible version of the plugin from [zip distribution](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954?pr=idea), but your IDEA **installation will be broken** (see the comment).

Comment: Please don't give this advice. Deleting the bundled Kotlin plugin breaks future patch upgrades and also breaks the digital signature of the app bundle on Mac OS X.

Comment: I honestly don't care at this point, I won't be using Kotlin for anything else but this project (which only supports the version i mentioned). If I ever need to update I'll just re-install. Thank you so much for this solution!

Comment: Sometimes the current kotlin plugin version is broken. So you need to downgrade anyway