# IntelliJ: No autocomplete for Kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, kotlin

I'm working on a project with Kotlin plugins, but IntelliJ doesn't seem to have autocomplete for Kotlin. Is there any way to enable it or should I just deal with it.

Comment: Have you added a jar as module dependency?

Comment: @TimCastelijns My module dependencies contains tons of libraries, added a few myself but most are from gradle build. Is it relevant to Kotlin?

Comment: @TimCastelijns There seems to be more wrong with my Kotlin http://i.imgur.com/3R3W5hz.png http://i.imgur.com/1X3ponF.gif

Comment: Which exactly versions of IntelliJ IDEA and Kotlin are you using? The Kotlin plugin certainly does support intellisense.

Comment: @yole 1.0.0 beta 1038 and latest intellij 15.0.4 i believe

Comment: @yole check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654657/intellij-kotlin-error-causes-mouse-flicker-and-errors-in-code I have more problems with Kotlin, hope you know a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You broke your Kotlin install by deleting the shipping Kotlin plugin and trying to downgrade (*which some very authoritative people said you shouldn't attempt*).  There are at least 4 Stack Overflow questions covering your issue now including this one.

See also (*your other questions*):

- [IntelliJ: Kotlin error causes mouse flicker and errors in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654657/intellij-kotlin-error-causes-mouse-flicker-and-errors-in-code)
- [How to downgrade Kotlin in Intellij 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649488/how-to-downgrade-kotlin-in-intellij-15)
- [IntelliJ (using gradle): Can't find Kotlin plugin even though it's installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651561/intellij-using-gradle-cant-find-kotlin-plugin-even-though-its-installed)

Read those, fix your Kotlin to 1.0.0, and upgrade your project to use Kotlin 1.0.0 dependencies (Kotlin itself and any third party to ensure they are compatible).

Any other Kotlin problems you have before then ARE RELATED to this one.  New stack overflow questions just confuses the situation for everyone involved.