# IntelliJ: Kotlin error causes mouse flicker and errors in code

Tags: intellij-idea, intellisense, lag, kotlin, flicker

I'm using IntelliJ 15 with Kotlin beta-1038, and I'm getting this error at the bottom of eclipse.

```
Internal Error occurred while analyzing this expression:
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ExternalOverridabilityCondition: Provider org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.ErasedOverridabilityCondition not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at kotlin.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toCollection(_Collections.kt:949)
    at kotlin.CollectionsKt.toCollection(Unknown Source)
    at kotlin.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toArrayList(_Collections.kt:942)
    at kotlin.CollectionsKt.toArrayList(Unknown Source)
    at kotlin.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.toList(_Collections.kt:973)
    at kotlin.CollectionsKt.toList(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverridingUtil.<clinit>(OverridingUtil.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.generateFakeOverrides(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.computeNonDeclaredFunctions(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:202)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.access$computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:389)
    at org.j...
```

Every Kotlin file I touch becomes full of errors and my mouse will flicker and I'll lag when I hover over any of the code. I also don't have intellisense.

However, I can compile and run the project and my changes in the kotlin files will work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4 bundles Kotlin 1.0 release. You broke your Kotlin installation because you followed the incorrect advice given to you at [How to downgrade Kotlin in Intellij 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649488/how-to-downgrade-kotlin-in-intellij-15). To fix your installation, you need to reinstall IntelliJ IDEA from the original installer.

Comment: As I stated before, newer versions of Kotlin aren't compatible with my project, is there any way to make this version work with intellij?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question but maybe you should think about porting your project to Kotlin 1.0. It seems like using a pre-1.0 Beta version of a language is going to cause you more and more trouble going forward.

Comment: @CaseyB How would I go about that? I'm new to IntelliJ, Gradle and Kotlin, do you reckon it's hard?

Comment: Upgrading the library is very easy, just go to Preferences > Plugins and search Kotlin. There should be a button to update there. As for making your code conform to 1.0 as opposed to what you're using now that's going to depend on your code and I can't really say without seeing it. I'd recommend updating and seeing what goes wrong.

Comment: There have been very few changes between 1.0.0-rc-1036 and the final 1.0.0 build. Most likely the only thing you need to do in order to upgrade is change the Kotlin version in your build.gradle from 1.0.0-rc-1036 to 1.0.0.